# Sort Chrome bookmarks by date newest first

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

How can I do this? This is one of the things I miss most from Firefox is the bookmark manager. So unorganized in Chrome, and no way to see one created before or after if using the search.

I've read these which tell me I cant:

- [Where is the SORT BOOKMARKS BY DATE option? - Google Chrome Help ...](https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B0EaLhDnRh4N0)
- [Cannot Sort Bookmarks by Date? - Google Chrome Help - Google Support](https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B0swKZW8ZKqkg)
- [How do i revert alphabetically sorted tabs to chronological order ...](https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B0guL0GB5u1yc)
- [How to sort chrome bookmarks by date - Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-sort-chrome-bookmarks-by-date)

That last one links an ext that isn't compatible with my Chromium or it might work. Unfortunately, it just stopped being open source.

The extensions I've found mostly sort by name:

- [SuperSorter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/supersorter/hjebfgojnlefhdgmomncgjglmdckngij?hl=en) is only alphabetical.
- [Recent Bookmarks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/recent-bookmarks/olndffocioplakeilhkgenfgdincjlpn) is helpful.
- There seemed to be a better one quoted below, but the links are dead:

  > [Chrome Bookmarks Sorter](http://jamesburgess.co.uk/blog/wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/download.php?id=2) is a handy tool (for Windows) which will allow users to sort bookmarks recursively by name or date added through all of your bookmark folders.
  >
  > -- https://superuser.com/questions/464454/how-to-sort-bookmarks-by-date-in-chrome-web-browser#answer-464464

I've found the Bookmarks location, in Ubuntu its: ~/.config/chromium/Default/Bookmarks. Its in json format and it looks like the alphabetizer exts just sort and replace the "id": "225" number in alpha order, so I could probably script the same to reorder by date. Anyone have pointers to a script that already does this?

EDIT: I just answered someone elses question on this topic at SU. So I'm linking that answer here as it has another approach to scripting a reordering back to date sorted:
https://superuser.com/a/1542328/388883

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Rewind](https://rewind.netlify.com/) (disclaimer: I'm the author)

It does sort bookmarks by date newest first, but it also displays the bookmarks you saved on the same date one year ago, two years ago and so on.

Comment: That's interesting, thanks, but it doesnt restore the date order. Rather coincidentally, I just answered someone elses question on this topic at SU (will add a link). In the back of my mind, I remembered posting something about the ids. And you reminded me it was here. On my other answer is more information on how to script the restoration of date order. Obviously your handy with coding, maybe you could incorporate it into your extension, and I could post a link to it on the Google Support page.

Comment: Even Rewind cannot do that extremely simple task that just show *ALL* bookmarks I have by date – in the same time. Without the need to explicitly select the appropriate day of the month for showing the bookmarks. Pity!